# Adding a Static Marker to Google Places Search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found this example for Google Maps API Places Search that I really like. - [Places Search](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/places/places-search.html?r=257) The only other thing I would like to add is a Static Marker at a specific Lat/Lng so that when the search results are giving they can see the relationship from the static place to the search results. I know how to add markers... just doesn't seem to load with this code. Any idea of how this would be done would be much appreciated.